# How to bind the borderBrush property of a textbox to a property in viewmodel, type conversion error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a textbox in xaml with a borderbrush property as follows:

```
<textbox BorderBrush="{Binding MyBrush}" />
```

inside view model I have defind the property

```
public System.Windows.Media.Brushes MyBrush {get;set;}
```

but I cannot set a value to this property

```
void method()
{
 MyBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
}
```

the compiler error is : cannot implicitly convert type System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush to System.Windows.Media.Brushes

Answer (score 4):

change

```
public System.Windows.Media.Brushes MyBrush {get;set;}
```

to

```
public System.Windows.Media.Brush MyBrush {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It resolved the problem!! but I don't know why when I hover over the text box its border color changes from red to the default color!! very strange!! any idea what do I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

`Brushes` is a static class containing pre-defined brush instances.

The type of your property should be [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use INotifyPropertyChanged. The code like :

```
private System.Windows.Media.Brush _myBrush
public System.Windows.Media.Brush MyBrush {
    get { return _myBrush; }
    set {
        if(value != _myBrush) {
            _myBrush = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyBrush");
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    // ....
}
```